# Adding Contact Numbers to Dataframe by Weight

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

This function is intended to add phone numbers to a "Phone" column in the "data" dataframe by weight, using account number as the primary key.

Weights (descending):

1. home phone
2. office phone
3. cell phone
4. office phone 2

If the higher-weight number is null, it then looks for a phone number in the next dataframe.

```
def addContact(dataDF, emailDF, homeDF, office1DF, cellDF, office2DF) :
    
    dataDF = pd.merge(dataDF, emailDF, on = "account", how = "left")
    
    dataDF = pd.merge(dataDF, homeDF, on = "account", how = "left")

    for index, row in dataDF.iterrows() :
        if(pd.isnull(row['Phone'])) :
            find = office1DF[office1DF['account'] == row['account']]
            if (pd.isnull(row['Phone'])) :
                dataDF.at[index, 'Phone'] = find['Phone']
            else :
                find = cellDF[cellDF['account'] == row['account']]
                if (pd.isnull(row['Phone'])) :
                    dataDF.at[index, 'Phone'] = find['Phone']
                else :
                    find = office2DF[office2DF['account'] == row['account']]
                    if (pd.isnull(row['Phone'])) :
                        dataDF.at[index, 'Phone'] = find['Phone']

    return dataDF
```

While most of the cells are covered by "home phone", the subsequent phone searches and additions are not working. I get cell values such as: "1193 NaN Name: Phone, dtype: object". How can I adjust the code to update the main DF cell values with the phone numbers when the main cell's current value is null?

Tried using series.len() to check if the length of the cell values are zero. Tried checking if the phone number series is null. Tried checking if the main dataframe's value is null AFTER updating.

Comment: put a try and except block
import traceback

example:


try:
    object.bad_attr
except Exception as exc:
    traceback.print_exception(exc)


print those values and see for yourself

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you have mock input data to go with your question? As recommended in [ask] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Could you provide some example data from each dataframe? It's tricky to help without knowledge of how they're structured.